# Como criar um algoritmo recursivo para encontrar a profundidade de uma lista

Tags: python-3.x, recursão

Estou a tentar criar um algoritmo recursivo para encontrar a profundidade duma lista, ou seja qual é o numero maior de `nested lists`, mas isto está complicado, não consigo encontra-lo. Percebo o percurso que o algoritmo tem que fazer, mas ainda não entendi claramente como o tem que fazer e como implementa-lo. Se alguém poderia-me ajudar a perceber melhor como faze-lo, seria fixe.

O que eu percebi até agora é que cada vez que um elemento é uma lista, temos que aumentar uma variável contador, mas não sei bem como relacionar esta variável com as chamadas recursivas.

Gostaria de saber o processo para chegar a solução e não uma solução, porque assim perceberia melhor como funciona a recursividade...

Já vi algumas soluções recursivas no [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039103/counting-deepness-or-the-deepest-level-a-nested-list-goes-to), como por exemplo esta:

```
def flat(l):
    depths = []
    for item in l:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            depths.append(flat(item))
    if len(depths) > 0:
        return 1 + max(depths)
    return 1
```

Mas mesmo assim não é fácil compreender o porque de todas as chamadas e de todos os passos...

Answer (score 1):

Recursão com explicação teórica é ainda mais difícil de se entender, então vamos ver na prática:

```
count = 0
def flat(l):
    global count
    count += 1
    depths = []
    print "- entrando em for, flat n:", count
    for item in l:
        print item
        if isinstance(item, list):
            print "- e lista, entramos em recursao..."
            print "depths.append(flat(", item, "))"
            depths.append(flat(item))
    print "- saindo de for, chamada flat n: ", count
    count -= 1
    if len(depths) > 0:
        print "- depths: ", depths, "retorno de 1 +", max(depths)
        return 1 + max(depths)
    print "- retornamos 1, pois depths esta vazia"
    return 1

print flat(["A", ["B", ["C", ["D"]]]])
```

Para `flat([1, [2]])` é como se tivéssemos:

```
flat([1, 
   flat([2]) 
])
```

Depois de rodar o programa, você vai compreender como funciona a implementação.

Eu tenho este código que fiz há muito tempo, nele você pode ver o mesmo, só que ele retorna uma nova lista com todos os elementos (mais uma implementação para que você possa analisar):

```
def return_all_items(i_list, end_list):
    for value in i_list:
        if isinstance(value, list):
            return_all_items(value, end_list)
        else:
            end_list.append(value)

>> lists_in_list = [["A", ["B"]], "C", "D", ["E", "F"]]
>> list_results = []
>> return_all_items(lists_in_list, list_results)
>> list_results
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
```

Comment: Você poderia ter lido, né? Quando eu mostrei o segundo código foi com intenção que você olhasse, analisasse, e adaptasse como mais uma implementação. É fácil de adaptar.

Answer (score -1):

Eu acho que a melhor forma de entender isso é pensar de baixo para cima.

Por exemplo:

```
arvore1 = [ 1, 2]
profundidade1 = 1

arvore2 = [ 4, 5]
profundidade2 = 1

arvore3 = [ 3, [ 1, 2]]
profundidade3 = 1 + profundidade1

arvore4 = [ 3, [1, 2], [ 4, 5]]
profundidade4 = 1 + max(profundidade1, profundidade2)
```

Então podemos dizer que a profundidade máxima de uma árvore é igual 1 + a maior profundidade das sub-árvores.

Comment: Porque o downvote? Eu poderia melhorar a resposta se soubesse.